# How can I get the href value from a list?

Tags: list, get, include, href

I am trying to get the href value after I click on it, so I can use then the `<?php include 'list'; ?>` to load the content of the php page I'd clicked before. I was trying something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('list').click(function)
var page=$(href);

<ul id="list">
<li><a href="mypage.php">Mypage</a> </li>
<li><a href="mypage2.php">Mypage2</a> </li>
```

So I can load a paragraph in my page using the content of the link I clicked before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the href value, then load the content of the linked page using the proper selectors and any appropriate jQuery ajax function, like [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list > li a').click(function(event) {
        var page = this.attr("href");

        // Here should go your ajax code or what-have-you to load the content.
        // If you use an ajax function, the url will be equal to the var page.
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // or "GET" may be better for your needs
            url: page,
            data: "",
            success: function(content) {
                console.log("ajax success");
                $("#divID").html(content);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("ajax error");
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log("ajax complete");
            }
        });
    });
});

<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="mypage.php">Mypage</a> </li>
  <li><a href="mypage2.php">Mypage2</a> </li>
</ul>
```

The code was missing the hash telling jQuery to find the id 'list'.  The '#list > li a' tells jQuery to apply the code block to all 'li a' children of #list.

Comment: //Thanks for your response,Should i load it with ajax or using php "include" ?

Comment: Have to use ajax to load the intended page's content into the current page.  I edited my code above to show you a working example (tried it in jsFiddle, and it worked).

Answer (score 1):

```
//thanks a lot for your response, i real apreciate it
//i finally used this and works fine
$(function() {
$("#team-tabs a").click(function() {
    var page= this.hash.substr(1);
    $.get(page+".php",function(gotHtml) {
        $("#cv-content").html(gotHtml);
    });
    return false;
});
});

//for this:
<ul id="team-tabs">
    <li><a href="#team/cv1">name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#team/cv2">name 2</a></li>
```